# Elegant way to convert a slice of one type to a slice of an equivalent type?

Tags: types, struct, go, slice

A motivating example:

Implementing various scheduling "strategies", which sort a list of Jobs.

```
type Job struct {
    weight int
    length int
}

// Given a slice of Jobs, re-order them.
type Strategy func([]Job) []Job

func Schedule(jobs []Job, strat Strategy) []Job {
    return strat(jobs)
}
```

One very simple strategy is to execute the shortest jobs first (disregarding their weight/priority).

```
func MinCompletionTimes(job []Job) []Job {
    // Hmm...   
}
```

Well, this strategy is nothing more than a sort on job.length, so let's use the sort package. Define a custom type, and implement sort.Interface...

```
type JobSlice []Job // Should probably be called MinCompletionTimesJobSlice

func (js JobSlice) Len() {
    return len(js)
}

func (js JobSlice) Less(i, j int) bool {
    return js[i].length < js[j].length
}

func (js JobSlice) Swap(i, j int) {
    js[i], js[j] = js[j], js[i]
}
```

Hooray, now to back to our simple strategy...

```
func MinCompletionTimes(jobs []Job) []Job {
    sort.Sort([]JobSlice(jobs)) // cannot convert jobs (type []Job) to type []JobSlice
    return jobs
}
```

Er...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

<s>First of all, I don't see `Jobs` defined anywhere even though you use it like `jobs []Jobs`.</s>

I think you mean `Job` since the error states `cannot convert jobs (type []Job)`, so I'll assume that when you're doing `[]Jobs`, you really mean `[]Job`.

---

If so, then with this, y You're trying to convert a slice of `Job` to a slice of `JobSlice`, the which has an underlying type of `[]Job`.

```
[]JobSlice(jobs) // converting a slice of Job to a slice of slices of Job?
```

In other words, you're trying to convert `[]Job` to effectively `[][]Job`. Instead I think you just wanted to convert your `[]Job` to `JobSlice`

```
JobSlice(jobs)
```

---

So taking out a bunch of the code, you can see that this conversion will work.

```
type Job struct {
    weight int
    length int
}

type JobSlice []Job

func main() {
    x := []Job{{},{}}

    y := JobSlice(x)
    z := []Job(y)

    fmt.Println(x, y, z)
}
```